# Where to put VirtualHost files for brew's httpd24?

Tags: homebrew, apache

I have installed `httpd24` via brew by running `brew install httpd24`

However I am not sure where to put a virualhost definition files in the file system.

I ran this command `/usr/local/bin/apachectl -S` and there is the output

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using mbp.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
Group: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
```

And here is a `tree` output

```
$ tree /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4
├── extra
│   ├── httpd-autoindex.conf
│   ├── httpd-dav.conf
│   ├── httpd-default.conf
│   ├── httpd-info.conf
│   ├── httpd-languages.conf
│   ├── httpd-manual.conf
│   ├── httpd-mpm.conf
│   ├── httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
│   ├── httpd-ssl.conf
│   ├── httpd-userdir.conf
│   ├── httpd-vhosts.conf
│   └── proxy-html.conf
├── httpd.conf
├── magic
├── mime.types
└── original
    ├── extra
    │   ├── httpd-autoindex.conf
    │   ├── httpd-dav.conf
    │   ├── httpd-default.conf
    │   ├── httpd-info.conf
    │   ├── httpd-languages.conf
    │   ├── httpd-manual.conf
    │   ├── httpd-mpm.conf
    │   ├── httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
    │   ├── httpd-ssl.conf
    │   ├── httpd-userdir.conf
    │   ├── httpd-vhosts.conf
    │   └── proxy-html.conf
    └── httpd.conf
```

Comment: `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like a good place to start, it will either contain the vhosts or tell you where to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to edit the file `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`.

Search for and uncomment the following two lines (remove the `#` at the beginning of the line):

```
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/mod_vhost_alias.so
#Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then edit the file `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to suit your needs.